# NameError: name 'self' is not defined в Python

Tags: python, ооп, классы, синтаксис

Я изучаю питон, но столкнулся с вот такой проблемой, и не могу понять в чем дело:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined D:\pygame>python alien_invasion.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.8)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pygame\alien_invasion.py", line 5, in <module>
    class AlienInvasion:
  File "D:\pygame\alien_invasion.py", line 11, in AlienInvasion
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Вот скриншот кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код текстом, а не скрином. Думаю, дело в том, что Вы пропустили табуляцию после определения конструктора. В коде с 9 по 14 строку нужно поставить `tab`

Comment: У вас одно слово self а второе слово явно не self неужели разницу не видите? IDE для вас даже подсветила эти слова в разные цвета. Ну а если вы даже не понимаете что в скрипте происходит то нужно начинать читать литературу для чайников.

Comment: @NaClnik согласен, но без скрина, вряд ли поняли в чем проблема=) и в python принято использовать пробелы, а не tab

Comment: а почему ты смог скопировать в вопрос текст ошибки но не смог скопировать код?

Comment: @Dmitry, это понятно, просто по умолчанию ide и так ставят пробелы вместо табов. Поэтому не уточнил

Comment: @NaClnik насколько я вижу там Sublime и не уверен в этом утверждении. Честно для меня Sublime - это сильно прокаченый блокнот и я совершенно без понятния как он себя ведет. Могу ошибаться

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код:

```py
class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
    pygame.init() # Вот отсюда начиная, у вас не верны отступы
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
```

Должно быть:

```py
class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init() 
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
```

Все что относится к методу класса, должно иметь отступ 2/4 пробела от определения метода. Если обратиться к коду с ошибкой, то вы используете `self`-переменную вне метода, и в данном ключе этой переменной просто не существует. О чем и говорит вам ошибка.